# Как передавать на письме протяжность слова?

Tags: корректура

- Эй ты, кар-р-рась желторотый!

Так правильно или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариантов оформления протяжного звучания достаточно. Многое зависит от авторского вИдения и восприятия:

*— Он мне-е-ее нуже-е... ен... — негромко завыла она, прижимая руки к  груди.*

*— Сере-е-ежа, — ласково, нараспев произнесла она и, слегка покачивая головой, не веря в реальность этой встречи, тихо повторила по слогам: — Се-ре-жа.*

*Девочка встряхнула головой, отбросила волосы на плечи и произнесла нараспев:

– Приве-е-ет… Ты ру-у-сская?

– Русская! – обрадовалась я.

– Меня зову-у-т На-а-стя, а тебя?*

*Так манерно растягивать слова могла лишь она одна.

– А что-о-о, не похо-о-оже? Как я тебе больше нра-а-а-влюсь, брюнеткой или блонди-и-инкой?*

*В голове у него звучал пронзительный крик Марли: «Папа-а-а!» — и слова старушки на автобусной остановке...*

А **кар-р-рась** Ваш желторотый воспринимается очень даже хорошо, понятно.

**Дополнение**
При разделении слова используется дефис (без пробелов), причем при его постановке возможна авторская вариативность. Вот примеры "протяжности" слова **нет** у одного и того же автора ([**А. Князева. Хранительница царских тайн**](http://loveread.me/read_book.php?id=33843&p=21)):

— (...)Ты видел пожар… и думаешь, все кончено… Не-е-е-е-т… У нас миллион лиц…

— Не-е-ет… — покачала головой Полина. — Было в этом что-то неестественное. Ненастоящее.

— Не-е-е-ет. Стерва, она больше нападает, а феминистка — защищается.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно.

Я, по крайней мере, именно так делаю: оставляю согласный первому слогу, второй черездефисно "раскатываю", третий повторяю в следующем слоге.

Нет, можно, конечно, раскатиться мысью по древу, только зачем? Допустимо и без дефисов, что смотрится хуже, имхо.

> – Я, девицы несмышленые, первая поднимаю голос за коллективное письмо…
>   **Уррра!..**
>
> – Ура!.. Письмо фрейлейн!.. Сейчас, сию минуту! – подхватили девочки.
>
> – Выпускные-то как бесчинствуют!.. – заслышав это «ура», пожимали
>   плечами «вторые».

([Л. Чарская](https://www.litres.ru/lidiya-charskaya/bolshoy-dzhon/chitat-onlayn/page-8/))

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Библіотека для чтенія, Том 39](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ZAQNAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA461&lpg=PA461&dq=%D0%A3%D1%80%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B0!&source=bl&ots=746wR2s6D-&sig=iMQmxltnwJrOvD1_a2XkLSFiBBk&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3w7zYwsTZAhUJWywKHQqXALIQ6AEIXDAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Или вот, просто погуглила:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В последнем случае я бы повторила звук ***р***: *гр-р-рабят!*

Два собеседования в Грамоте.ру:

- о [гласных](http://forum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=5354);
- о [согласных](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=287818).

Answer (score 2):

[Ответ справочной службы русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=284707%20)

Есть четкое правило: для передачи произношения по слогам с разными целями, для передачи протяжного звучания гласных, раскатистого р и других особенностей произношения используется дефис, например: Антропка! Антропка-а-а!.. — кричал он с упорным и слезливым отчаянием, долго, долго вытягивая последний слог (Тургенев); Ну о-о-очень навязчивая реклама! (из газеты); Это было р-р-р-революционно!; «П-п-роходите, п-п-пожалуйста», — сказал он заикаясь. См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2006. § 113.